# Sample program in pthread to simulate the thread priority

Tags: c++, multithreading

Consider thread 1 has the higher priority than thread 2.

Is there is any sample program to simulate that thread 1 has taken the highest priority when compared to thread2?

I encountered this question because there is an option called thread priority in pthreads.

As per my knowledge thread priority is used by OS for scheduling policy and there is no control on programmer.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: It would add significant meat to your question if you added a reference to the "option called thread priority in pthreads" to which you refer. Are you referring to [`pthread_setschedparam`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setschedparam.3.html) ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about "simulating", but there sure is a function to control thread priority. And it is available to the programmer.

Read the documentation for [`pthread_setschedparam()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_setschedparam);